# how to match this text from between html tags using preg_match

Tags: php, preg-match

I need to match

```
<TD WIDTH=30%><B>Joining Date</B></TD></TR>STRINGTOBEMATCHED</TABLE>
```

with preg_match... tried using preg_quote but still, there's something wrong with the string, preg_match thinks B is an oprator of some kind..

Comment: That html is invalid, good luck with using regex to parse that

Comment: Why you are still now using ancient `tags` and `attributes` in `21st` century.

Comment: i'm not, i'm to extract this data from another webpage..

Comment: Which `text` ? `Joining Date` or `STRINGTOBEMATCHED`, be more specific about the which text/htm you want to parse  ?

Comment: I need to extract STRINGTOBEMATCHED. Joining Date is a part of the pages' text..

Comment: Obvious "what have you tried?" comment.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you read [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php/3577662#3577662) about HTML parsing. Nowadays there are loads of XML/HTML parsers you can use.

Since the HTML code is very badly written (attribute values have no quotes, text occurs inside `table` but outside `tr`), it's hard to parse the HTML code.

Still, to answer your question, one can use this code, since you need the string to be matched to be between the `</tr>` and `</table>` tag:

```
$var = "<TD WIDTH=30%><B>Joining Date</B></TD></TR>STRINGTOBEMATCHED</TABLE>";
$regex = "%</TR>(.*?)</TABLE>%i";
$matches = null;
preg_match($regex, $var, $matches);

$result = $matches[1];
```

but I strongly recommend you to use a library denoted in the abovementioned thread.